# What does this array declaration mean?

Tags: vb6

code :
`Public ArryProErrorCode() As String, TempArry`

I don't know what TempArry means when declare ArryProErrorCode() array?

can anyone explain it?
thx

Comment: Don't spam tags. If this is a question about VB6 then don't tag it VBA and VB.NET. The descriptions for those tags explicitly state that you should not do that. Don't try to trick people into viewing your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TempArray` is another variable declared on the same line but because you did not specify its type, it is a `Variant`.

You can declare multiple variables on the same line e.g.

```
Dim var1 As String, var2 As String, var3 As Long
```

Comment: A minor addition to this otherwise perfect answer: `TempArray` in that case would only be a `Variant` without a fitting preceding [DefType statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/deftype-statements), e.g. `DefLng A-Z` would result in `TempArray` to be a `Long`.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Thanks for sharing this! I have no knowledge of this statement.

Comment: I made it a habit of the first 2 lines of code always being `Option Explicit` and `DefLng A-Z` _(any data type will do, I settled for Long)_ This forces variables to be a "strong" data type, i.e. not `Variant`, and prevents some of the under-the-hood implicit data type conversion of VB _and_ throws a compile time error for forgotten `As <type>` like in that example.